# How to import numkt (kotlin's numpy wrapper) into jupyter notebook to be used with kotlin kernel

Tags: numpy, kotlin, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed the kotlin kernel into my jupyter notebook environment using Anaconda. There are several libraries available by default like I can %use lets-plot

I'd really like to use the numpy wrapper which is sometimes called knumpy, kotlin-numpy or numkt

Import statements I see for the package include:

```
import org.jetbrains.numkt.*
import org.jetbrains.numkt.core.*
import org.jetbrains.numkt.math.*
```

from places like [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-numpy)

I can currently use the statement: %use numpy
and I get the error: Unresolved reference: numkt

I'd really like to get this functionality into my environment so I can actually do things.

How would I install/import this functionality into/from my anaconda environment.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Remove all those imports and replace them with:

```
%use numpy
```

Here you can find `knumpy` very basic [example](https://github.com/luhtonen/kotlin-jupyter/blob/master/samples/KNumpy.ipynb).